# Rubik's Group Question - Commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, rubiks-cube

Suppose that $f: G \rightarrow S_C$ be the action of Rubik's group $G$ on the collection of $C$ of corner cubelets. 
So if $C_1$ and $C_2$ be distinct corner cubelets. Show that there is a move $M \in G$ which maps FRU (front right up) to $C_1$ and FRD (front right down) to $C_2$. 
Then find a move $N$ in rubiks group $G$ which exchanges the cubelets FRU and FRD but leaves all the other corner cubelets in their place.

I am really lost on the first part of this problem. And I think for the second part, I must find a commutators in order to leave the other corner cubelets in one place with just exchanging FRU and FRD. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, first show it for the case when $C_1$ and $C_2$ are neighbors (this is physically obvious if you fiddle around with an actual cube, moving the FRU-FR-FRD stack around as a unit; how much you prose you need to describe that as a proof is a good question).

Then show that for each possible relative position between $C_1$ and $C_2$, there is a single rotation which makes $C_1$ and $C_2$ neighbors. They can then be moved to FRU/FRD as described above.

---

The wording of the exercise can sound like you're supposed to *use* the result of the first part to solve the second, but I think that would be a misunderstanding -- there's no obvious way the first part would be helpful for the second. Instead the point is probably that you're supposed later to *combine* these two parts to conclude that every transposition of corners can be made (as a conjugation of the FRU-FRD exchange).

Commutators *alone* will not do you any good in this part, because a commutator is always an *even* permutation and the one you're trying to create is odd.

Observe, however that if you start by making an F quarter-turn, what you need to reach a state with FRU and FRD exchanged is just a cyclic permutations of some of the front corners. Do you know how to construct 3-cycles as commutators between two permutations whose supports intersect at a single element only?