# Rubik's cube question showing surjectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, rubiks-cube

Suppose $f: G \rightarrow S_C$ be the action of Rubik's group G on the collection $C$ of corner cubelets.

I want to show that the action $f$ is onto $S_C$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that [there is a move that interchanges two neighboring corners and leaves the other 6 corners where they were](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513201/rubiks-group-question-commutators), show that $f(G)$ contains a set of generators for $S_C$.

(Hint: You can list all of the corner positions in an order such that each position is physically a neighbor of the one that comes after it).